# Abel's Summation Formula with Discrete Calculus

Tags: combinatorics, summation, finite-differences, discrete-calculus

I would like to prove the following version of Abel summation
$$\sum_{k=1}^nu_kv_k = u_{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^nv_k -  \sum_{k=1}^n\Delta u_k\left[  \sum_{p=1}^kv_p\right]$$ where $\Delta u_k = u_{k+1} - u_k.$
I can see how to unravel this sum by hand and show this equality, but I'm trying to construct a proof by discrete calculus operator identities and the fundamental theorem of calculus for discrete functions: $\sum_{k=1}^nu_k = (\Delta^{-1}u)_{n+1}-(\Delta^{-1}u)_{1}$

**My attempt:**

We have the product formula:
$$\Delta^{-1}(u\Delta w) = uw  - \Delta^{-1}(Ew\Delta u)$$
with $Eu_k = u_{k+1}$
Set $v= \Delta w.$ Then
$$\Delta^{-1}(uv) = u\Delta^{-1}v  - \Delta^{-1}(\Delta u E \Delta^{-1}v)$$
or $$\sum_{k=1}^nu_kv_k = (u_{n+1}- u_1)\sum_{k=1}^n v_k  - \sum_{k=1}^n \Delta u_k (\Delta^{-1}v)_{k+1}$$
If correct, this seems very close to what I'd like to show but I don't see how to complete the argument. Is there a way to elegantly obtain this formula via discrete calculus operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can show the formula using *summation by parts*
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\Delta b_k =\big[a_k b_k\big]_{k=1}^{n+1}-\sum_{k=1}^n b_{k+1}\Delta a_k\tag{1}
\end{align*}
In order to apply (1) we set
\begin{align*}
V_k:=\begin{cases}
v_1+v_2+\cdots+v_{k-1}&\qquad k\geq 2\\
0&\qquad k=1
\end{cases}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
so that we can use $\color{blue}{v_k=\Delta V_k, k\geq 1}$.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^n}\color{blue}{u_k
> v_k}
> &=\sum_{k=1}^n u_k\Delta V_k\tag{$\to (2)$}\\
> &=\big[u_k V_k\big]_{k=1}^{n+1}-\sum_{k=1}^n V_{k+1}\Delta u_k\tag{$\to (1)$}\\
> &=u_{n+1}V_{n+1}-u_1V_1-\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{k}v_j\Delta {u_k}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=u_{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n v_k-\sum_{k=1}^n\Delta {u_k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}v_j}\tag{$\to (2)$}\\
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.